# Importing users into cognito user pool with md5 passwords

Tags: amazon-cognito, md5sum

We are trying to migrate our user management to Amazon Cognito. In this process, we need to import the existing users in our database to Cognito.

We have the md5 hashed passwords associated with the users. I just want to confirm if we can make use of them to set the passwords to the imported users in Cognito.

To be clear instead of sending a plain text password in API request can I send the md5 of the password?

Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am on the Cognito team, and that is not possible at this point. Password import is not supported, because security best practices require that passwords are not available as plain text, and we don't support importing hashes.

Comment: Thanks, Ionut. The reply is really helpful to me